# How to create new iWeb Theme (iLife)

Tags: mac, themes, templates, iweb, ilife

Is it possible to create new iWeb Theme? How can I do it? Is there any place where I can download themes other than those that came with iLife?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a webpage that explains how to create your own templates.
http://11mystics.com/tools/iweb/create-iweb-templates/

There are other a few places to purchase templates which can be found if you google 'iweb templates'

Hope this helps.

Comment: The link with times can die... sad but it's internet.